# How can I improve database design for my subscription based billing system?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design

I am moving from **Credits-based billing system** to **Subscription-based billing system**. Till now, I used to check the number of credits a user had and based on that; I used to E-mail user whether the renewal has been done or not. In the event of a first purchase, I used to activate a plan that user has selected.

I am now shifting to the subscription-based billing system in which I will store subscriptions with `validity` and I want to eliminate the credits part from the root. Here is the database schema for my new billing system. ***The issue with this schema is I can't process first purchase event as there is no solid way to know if a user is purchasing for the first time and if a user has paid the full amount or not. I am getting confused at each and every step of the change.***

[image]

Let me explain what issue I am facing. While the transaction is being processed, the `is_active` flag in `subscriptions` remains `null` which means a user can't perform any action on my software. But when a transaction is processed, User will return to my website and my website will mark the transaction `paid` which means a user has paid but as there is no connection between transactions and subscriptions, How would I know when to mark a subscription paid. In **TransactionController**, Transactions will be processed and in **SubscriptionController**, Subscription will be processed.

I haven't created the connection between subscription and transaction because in that case, I'll have to allow `nullable foreign keys` in a transaction because transactions can be for extra services too!

I am getting more confused by thinking more about it. I don't know what's the issue here but I know there is some issue with database design. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you dont want to change the DB, you can use joins. I can see there is a user_id is common in both transaction and subscription. When the transaction is complete you have to check which user_id is same as in the subscription.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I was thinking to put "first_purchase=>{true|false}" meta information in user_meta and check if it exists when the transaction is complete. In case if it exists, I can activate the subscription. Otherwise, I can renew the subscription and mark it active and is_renewal. Is this a good way to go?

Comment: If subscription has many types(like basic,premium, gold) than it can be problem in future. If its only one type, it will working.

Comment: Actually, there are two plans and three cycles. So according to you, It can be a problem.

Comment: yes it can be a problem. You should have to manage a connection between both tables or you can create a new table.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am missing. The connection between transactions and subscription tables.

Comment: Ok lets do it. When user select subscription all the values put in the session and save in db as well. After that go on transaction and complete it. If transaction is complete get the previous session and transaction response merge both of them and save into another table. After save value destroy that session.

Comment: When you subscribe another subscription or update subscription than you can check the user_id from new table so you get all the previous transactions and subscriptions both :)

Comment: Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Yes. That's what I have planned to do. With pen and paper, I found out that there is a way to identify first purchase. Here is what I am going to do. In transaction controller, I will check if a number of subscriptions a user has are 1 and is not active. If that condition is matched, I will activate the subscription and mark a transaction paid.

Comment: In case of renewals, I am chaning `is_renewals` column to `renewals` and changing datatype from `boolean` to `integer`. That way, In one subscription instance, I can see how many renewals are done and how much validity is left.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to change datatype and `is_renewal` column in the subscription table. It can work out as it is.

Comment: yes i just want to say same thing you dont need to change type

Answer (score 2):

This is what comes into my mind:

1. Add an end date and is_autorenew to your subscription
2. Add create- and payment initiation dates to your transaction
3. I would create a new table , e.g. booking, which holds user information, billing address, price and payment method. Imagine a case, when a guest is subscribing or a user is changing his address or the product price changes. These values need to be genuine.
4. Create 1:1 relations between booking and subscription and subscription and transaction
5. Enrich your transaction with returned values from your payment provider, such as customer_id or transaction_id.

This could be your base DB-Model. Now when someone buys anything, you will create 3 entries: booking, subscription and transaction, if everything goes well. If is_autorenew && is_active are true, run a cronjob which renews the subscription automatically. You can use the transaction_id in your transaction table for that. I would create a whole new subscription then and link it to the booking and transaction. Set the old subscription to inactive afterwards.

Hope this will help you a little.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a field `parent_id` for your subscription table.

The relationship between `subscription` and `transaction` will be 1:1.

Also, I suggest you just activate the user membership immediately (if you can), it gives you the following advantages:

1. the user experience will not be affected due to the lag of the acknowledgement of the transaction.
2. the relation between `subscription` and `transaction` is created instantly when the user attempted to initial a subscription. You could fill in the transaction id later when you receive the transaction_id.

Hope I helped.

p.s. Is this relevant to `php`?

Comment: Actually, I added `php` because Laravel is a PHP framework and by knowing that I am using laravel, I thought someone would suggest laravelish way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can activate subscription before payment is successful but that would create a loophole.

Comment: I want to activate membership immediately after payment is done.

Comment: what do you mean by loophole?

Comment: If I enable membership while a user is processing the payment, he/she can just cancel the payment and get their membership for free. But I misunderstood your words. I now understand that immediately means immediately after payment. And I figured out the solution for everything finallly.

Comment: Yes, you should set up a worker to terminate subscription with unsuccessful payment if you go for this approach

Comment: Yes. That can possible.